# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list') when trying to make "urban" slash command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My urban-dictionary command is working just fine as common text command but when I'm trying to make a slash command - my code breaks with `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'list')` error!
Here are my `options` for the command:

```
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "search",
            "description": "Term to search for",
            "type": 3,
            "required": true
        }
    ]
```

and my slash command code:

```js
let query = interaction.options.getString('search')

        query = encodeURIComponent(query);
        const { data: { list }, } = axios.get(`https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=${query}`).catch((err) => {})
        
        const [answer] = list;

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(answer.word)
        .setURL(answer.permalink)
        .setColor("#380002")
        .setDescription(trim(answer.definition))
        .addField("Example", trim(answer.example), false)
        .addField("Upvotes", `** ** ${answer.thumbs_up}`, true)
        .addField("Downvotes", `** ** ${answer.thumbs_down}`, true)
        .setFooter(`Author: ${answer.author}`);

        interaction.reply({embeds: [embed], ephemeral: false}).catch((err) => {})
```

So, any ideas on what's wrong? If you need more info I will answer in comments because I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: I believe you will have to `await` it

Comment: @MrMythical Yes, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Let me post it as a real answer...

Comment: @MrMythical sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.get` returns a `Promise`. This means that `axios.get(...).data` will be undefined. The simple fix is to add `await`:

```js
//async function
const { data: { list }, } = await axios.get(`...`).catch((err) => {})
```